Is there a way to send a message from a native MacOS app, to a Safari extension, then wait for a response?
So, according to Apple's documentation, when you use sendNativeMessage to send a message to your app from a Safari web extension, there is a callback for the response, and the example of the native beginRequest(with context:) function does supply a response.
However, the example for sending data from the native app to the javascript extension via SFSafariApplication.dispatchMessage(withName:, toExtensionWithIdentifier:, userInfo:) simply sends a message and logs an error if there is one, likewise the javascript side does nothing to respond.
Is there a way to send data from the native app to the javascript and get some data in response?
Furthermore, is there a way to send a single message to the javascript in the extension without having to open a persistent connection? (How does one even maintain a persistent connection with a Manifest V3 based extension?)
The obvious solution is to just send a message to the extension, hoping it's received and processed correctly, then separately receiving a message which is interrogated and inferred to be a response to the previous message. In the end it's the same result, I'm just looking to see if there's a better way.

No, it's designed to be stateless — with the exception of the callback that you already mentioned (in browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage). Chrome's native messaging API works the same way.
